# Access object properties in groovy using []

Tags: groovy

Say I have the following code in groovy:

```
class Human {
  Face face
}
class Face {
  int eyes = 2
}
def human = new Human(face:new Face())
```

I want to access the `eyes` property using the `[]`:

```
def humanProperty = 'face.eyes'
def value = human[humanProperty]
```

But this does not work as I expected (as this tries to access a property named 'face.eyes' on the Human object, not the eyes property on the human.face property).

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would need to evaluate the string to get to the property you require.  To do this, you can either do:

```
humanProperty.split( /\./ ).inject( human ) { obj, prop -> obj?."$prop" }
```

(that splits the `humanProperty` into a list of property names, then, starting with the `human` object, calls each property in turn, passing the result to the next iteration.

Or, you could use the Eval class to do something like:

```
Eval.x( human, "x.${humanProperty}" )
```

To use the `[]` notation, you would need to do:

```
human[ 'face' ][ 'eyes' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to simply execute:

```
def value = human['face']['eyes']
```

But if you don't know the values required ('face' and 'eyes'), there's also an easier and clearer way.

```
def str = "face.eyes"
def values = str.split("\\.")
def value = human[values[0]][values[1]]
```