# Groovy Dynamic List Interaction

Tags: grails, dynamic, groovy, grails-orm

I am using an older version of grails (1.1.1) and I am working on a legacy application for a government client.

Here is my question (in psuedo form):

I have a domain that is a Book.  It has a sub domain of type Author associated with it (1:many relationship).  The Author domain has a firstName and lastName field.

```
def c = Book.createCriteria()
      def booklist = c.listDistinct {
          author {
              order('lastName', 'asc')
              order('firstName', 'asc')
          }
}
```

Let's say I have a list of fields I want to use for an excel export later.  This list has both the author domain call and the title of the column I want to use.

```
Map fields = ['author.lastName' : 'Last Name', 'author.firstName', 'First Name']
```

How can I dynamically call the following code--

```
booklist.eachWithIndex(){
  key, value ->
  println key.fields
}
```

The intent is that I can create my Map of fields and use a loop to display all data quickly without having to type all of the fields by hand.

Note - The period in the string `'author.lastName'` throws an error when trying to output key`['author.lastName']` too.

Comment: Think this is basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/4077168/6509

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall the version of Groovy that came with Grails 1.1, but there are a number of language constructs to do things like this.  If it's an old version, some things may not be available - so your mileage may vary.

Map keys can be referenced with quotes strings, e.g.

```
def map = [:]
map."person.name" = "Bob"
```

The above will have a key of person.name in the map.

Maps can contain anything, including mixed types in Groovy - so you really just need to work around string escapes or other special cases if you are using more complex keys.

You can also use a GString in the above

```
def map = [:]
def prop = "person.name"
map."${prop}" = "Bob"
```

You can also get a map of property/value off of a class dynamically by the properties field on it.  E.g.:

```
class Person { String name;String location; }
def bob = new Person(name:'Bob', location:'The City')
def properties = bob.properties
properties.each { println it }
```