# Accessing a property with object."${property}"

Tags: groovy

I'm working on some dynamic filtering, and have this:

```
class Filterable {
    def statusId
    def secondaryFilterable
}
...
def filter = new Filter(validIds: [1], fieldName: 'statusId')
...
class Filter {

    def validIds = [] as Set
    def fieldName
    private boolean containsFieldValue(input) {
        def fieldValue = input."${fieldName}"
        return fieldValue in validIds
    }
}
```

Which works just fine for one property. However, now I need to filter by the secondary filterable - something like

```
def filter = new Filter(validIds: [1], fieldName: 'secondaryFilterable.statusId')
```

Which throws a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4077168/581845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted properties assume a dot is part of the property name.

A simple solution would be:

```
...
def fieldValue = fieldName.split(/\./).inject(input){ parent, property -> parent?."$property" }
...
```

This will recursively look up the field value using dot notation for child properties.

[I put up a working example here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/708001) on the Groovy web console.

Comment: Note: this example doesn't check for validity of the property — if the property doesn't exist, it may throw an error.  (Try `'foo.bar.badValue'` in the example link.)  If necessary, this can be prevented by adding a check using [`hasProperty`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Evaluating+the+MetaClass+runtime).