# Using a variable to extract value of property of an element in groovy using xmlSlurper

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, soapui, xmlslurper

I am using SoapUI to test webservices. The following string (in xml format) is my request:

```
<Request>
   <AC>
      <AssetID>1</AssetID>
      <Asset_Name>ABC</Asset_Name>
      <Asset_Number>1</Asset_Number>
   </AC>
   <AC>
      <AssetID>2</AssetID>
      <Asset_Name>XYZ</Asset_Name>
      <Asset_Number>2</Asset_Number>
   </Ac>
</Request>
```

I am using the following code in a groovy script to extract value of Asset_Number for each AC (The above xml string is stored in variable strRequest):

```
def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText("$strRequest")

x.AC.each { AC ->
assetNum = AC."Asset_Number"
<<do something with the assetNum>>
}
```

However, I wish to parameterize the above code to pick up Asset_Number for various types of assets (e.g. AC, Peripheral etc). The request xml for each asset is in the same format as above. If I replace 'AC' with variable name 'requestName' in above code:

```
//strRequest = xml request
def requestName //I will pick up value for this from a test case property
def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText("$strRequest")

x.(requestName.toString()).each { requestName ->
    assetNum = requestName."Asset_Number"
    <<do something with the assetNum>>
}
```

it shows the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script166.groovy: 35: The current scope already contains a variable of the name requestName @ line 35, column 2. { ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: The current scope already contains a variable of the name requestName
```

I have tried a solution mentioned in another post [Using a String as code with Groovy XML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506920/using-a-string-as-code-with-groovy-xml-parser?lq=1), but it doesn't serve my purpose.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code that's failing?

Comment: Seems a bit unclear for me.

Comment: @tim_yates I have added the failing code to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
x."$requestName".each
```

Comment: I tried using "$requestName" as follows:  
  
    `x."$requestName".each { "$requestName" ->  
    assetNum = "$requestName"."Asset_Number"  
    <<do something with the assetNum>> }`
  
but it shows me another error as follows:  
  
    `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script212.groovy: 31: expecting '}', found '->' @ line 31, column 18. "$requestName" -> ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found '->' @ line 31, column 18.`

Answer (score 0):

Why XmlSlurper? In SoapUI you can use XmlHolder

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def responseHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())

def resultFromResponse = responseHolder["here_is_your_xpath"]
assert someExpectedResult == resultFromResponse
```

And if you need to iterate via multiple xml nodes

```
resultFromResponse.each 
{
    assert result == resultFromResponse     
}
```