# "it" and xmlSlurper malfunction in groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have a very simple little iterator here

```
maps.each
{

    d = resXml.ResultSet.Row.it.text()
    log.info d

}
```

`it` is obviously the element name i'm trying to access the info in, and if i say `log.info it` instead of `log.info d` i do get the correct names (`A` new line `B` new line `C`), but doing like i just showed you results in nothing - so i went and checked one of the `it` returns manually (`d = resXml.ResultSet.Row.A.text()`) and i did get the result i was looking for.

I'm at a total loss, i'm not even sure how to search for this question - i'm using soapUI Open Source and maps is also from an xmlSlurper object but its format is fine: `[A,B,C]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your it is being interpreted as a property/node named "it".
XML."$it".andSoOn (using a g string) should work per [Using a variable to extract value of property of an element in groovy using xmlSlurper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366155/using-variable-to-extract-value-of-property-of-an-element-in-groovy-using-xmls)

This assumes it is a string.

Comment: uhm, my way works. Does exactly what i need it to and the way above is just a complicated way of iterating through multiple trees, i have one tree

Comment: Your answer is identical to what I've described above, but my answer explains why your question does not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Matt, teaches me for being up for 20 hours straight and too much coffee. You are absolutely correct

Answer (score -1):

By using:

```
d = resXml.ResultSet.Row."${it}".text()
```

or:

```
d = resXml.ResultSet.Row./${it}/.text()
```