# How to I use a variable reference within XMLSlurper statement

Tags: groovy, soapui, xmlslurper

I am using a groovy with XMLSlurper to validate my web service responses in soap ui pro.

I have the following code which works (expectedResponse is var that stores expected errorcode e.g. E0023) ...

```
if(expectedResponse2 in slurper.Body.createShipmentResponse.integrationFooter.errors.error.errorCode.collect{it.text()})
{
        result = "pass" 
}
```

But I would like to replace the 'integrationFooter.errors.error.errorCode' with a reference to a variable that I could supply from a SoapUI Pro datasource, because I am not always validating on the same response element. i.e if I am expecting the test to pass I might want to check that the status element is populated with 'Allocated'. If I am expecting the request to fail I want to validate that the errorCode field is populated with the correct errorCode e.g. 'E0023'.

If I have a variable called testElement in my groovyscript and I assign it the path of the element e.g. integrationFooter.errors.error.errorCode how do I refer to the variable within my XMLSlurper statement?

I tried the below code but it didn't work..

```
if(expectedResponse2 in slurper.Body.createShipmentResponse."${testElement}".collect{it.text()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string and handle each property in turn yourself...

Try:

```
def root = slurper.Body.createShipmentResponse
if(expectedResponse2 in testElement.tokenize( '.' ).inject( root ) { v, p ->
                            v?."$p"
                        }?.collect{ it.text() } ) {
    result = "pass" 
}
```

See [Access object properties in groovy using []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077168/access-object-properties-in-groovy-using)

That loops over the list `[ 'integrationFooter', 'errors', 'error', 'errorCode' ]`, starting with `slurper.Body.createShipmentResponse`.  So first time round, the inject returns `slurper.Body.createShipmentResponse.integrationFooter`. Then it calls `errors` on this object, and so on until it gets the final result which you can call `collect` on.

The `?.` operator just means it will keep going if it hits a null (and return null)

#### Inject explanation:

Given an object like this:

```
def obj = [ prop1:[ prop2:[ prop3: 'tim' ] ] ]
```

We can call:

```
assert obj.prop1.prop2.prop3 == 'tim'
```

However, if we were given the property name to read as a String:

```
def props = 'prop1.prop2.prop3'
```

Then this won't work (as there's no key `'prop1.prop2.prop3'`)

```
assert obj."$props" == 'tim'  // FAILS!
```

But we can split `props` on the full stop to get a list of properties:

```
def pList = props.tokenize( '.' )
assert pList == [ 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3' ]
```

Then, we can work through this list, starting with `obj`:

```
def result = pList.inject( obj ) { currentObject, property ->
    // Return the property from the currentObject (or null if currentObject is null)
    currentObject?."$property"
}
```

So for each element of `pList`, we do:

```
Step1:
    currentObject == obj
    property   == 'prop1'
    returns obj.prop1 -- [ prop2:[ prop3: 'tim' ] ]

Step2:
    currentObject == [ prop2:[ prop3: 'tim' ] ]
    property   == 'prop2'
    returns currentObj.prop2 -- [ prop3: 'tim' ]

Step3 (final step as pList is at an end now):
    currentObject == [ prop3: 'tim' ]
    property   == 'prop3'
    returns currentObj.prop3 -- 'tim'
```

So the final result is `'tim'`

Hope this explains it :-)

Comment: Tim, you're a legend! This works an absolute treat (added opening '{' for if body). I still need to do some reading to understand how the  (v, p -> v?."$p") works, but I was able to copy it in to script and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @tamnorris Cool (thanks for the fix with the `{` -- I've updated the answer).  If you want, I can post an example to show how the inject is working.  Could you accept this answer if it's solved your problem?  Have fun!

Comment: @TimYates. An example would be great. Thanks Tim.

Comment: @tamnorris added an example!  Let me know if it makes no sense... it's easier to explain with a whiteboard ;-)